# Xcode 6.1.1 crashes when opening project. Why?

Tags: xcode6.1

After upgrading Xcode to 6.1.1, there's one project I just can't open anymore. It happens while "Loading xxx...". Here's the dump:

```
Process:               Xcode [9343]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1.1 (6611)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6611000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       810788292
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [9343]
User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2014-12-04 09:13:16.198 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C68k)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        4D866B4F-CB26-6063-CCCD-E67B869C790D

Sleep/Wake UUID:       AFB5AAC7-3418-4089-9431-D5F33891A437

Time Awake Since Boot: 12000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1100 seconds

Crashed Thread:        10  Dispatch queue: IBPlatformToolRequestQueue.IBCocoaTouchFramework-EightAndLater

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A2008a
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (IBAssertionFailure): ASSERTION FAILURE: [item ibBaselineCount] >= 1
Reason:     An item that references the first attribute must have multiple baselines
File:       /SourceCache/IBAutolayoutFoundationIOS/IDEInterfaceBuilder-6254/AutolayoutFoundation/Model/IBAutolayoutCommon.m:221
Method:     CGFloat IBLayoutAttributeValueOfAttributeForItemInCoordinateSpaceOfItem(IBLayoutAttribute, NSObject<IBAutolayoutItem> *__strong, NSObject<IBAutolayoutItem> *__strong, IBUserInterfaceLayoutDirection)
UserInfo: {
    IBAbstractPlatformToolExceptionBacktrace = "  0. CoreFoundation           0x000000010e8d9f1d __exceptionPreprocess\n  1. libobjc.A.dylib          0x000000010d5c0bb7 objc_exception_throw\n  2. CoreFoundation           0x000000010e8d9b79 -[NSException raise]\n  3. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010cc7cb9a IBLayoutAttributeValueOfAttributeForItemInCoordinateSpaceOfItem\n  4. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010ccaef34 -[IBLayoutConstraint roundingAdjustmentWithUserInterfaceLayoutDirection:]\n  5. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010cc8f1c3 -[IBAutolayoutEngine _attemptToAddConstraint:toView:returningConstraintsOrConstraintAbstractionsMakingSystemOverConstrained:constraintsOrAbstractionsForRepresentedConstraintsBlock:]\n  6. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010cc8f43d -[IBAutolayoutEngine attemptToAddConstraint:toView:returningConstraintsMakingSystemOverConstrained:]\n  7. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010cc63009 +[IBAutolayoutArbiter attemptToAddConstraint:byModifyingLayoutEngine:mutuallyExclusiveConstraintBreakageStrategy:mutableConstraintsToAdd:mutableConstraintsToRemove:]\n  8. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010cc8d6be -[IBAutolayoutEngine performEngineBootstrappingConstraintAdditionOperationForAddingConstraint:]\n  9. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010cc8dc44 __90-[IBAutolayoutEngine iterateViewsAndGenerateRepresentedConstraintsAndMapToRealConstraints]_block_invoke662\n 10. CoreFoundation           0x000000010e813a45 __NSDictionaryEnumerate\n 11. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010cc8d9c6 -[IBAutolayoutEngine iterateViewsAndGenerateRepresentedConstraintsAndMapToRealConstraints]\n 12. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010cc882f3 -[IBAutolayoutEngine initWithArbitrationUnit:options:]\n 13. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x000000010cc6e818 -[IBAutolayoutArbitrationUnit computeStatus]\n 14. ???                      0x000000010b0987a5 [IBCocoaTouchTool computeAutolayoutStatusForRequest:document:]\n 15. IBFoundation             0x000000010cde08ef __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]_block_invoke\n 16. IBFoundation             0x000000010cde0686 -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]\n 17. IBFoundation             0x000000010cde0350 __88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke\n 18. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000111ed5af4 _dispatch_client_callout\n 19. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000111ec2e95 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke\n 20. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000111ed5af4 _dispatch_client_callout\n 21. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000111ec1265 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF\n 22. CoreFoundation           0x000000010e841fe9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__\n 23. CoreFoundation           0x000000010e804eeb __CFRunLoopRun\n 24. CoreFoundation           0x000000010e804486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific\n 25. Foundation               0x000000010d17db42 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]\n 26. IBFoundation             0x000000010cdbf955 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:]\n 27. IBFoundation             0x000000010cdbfa2f -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingSocket:]\n 28. IBFoundation             0x000000010cdbfcf2 +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main]\n 29. ???                      0x000000010b0cae90 [IBViewRenderer .cxx_destruct]\n 30. libdyld.dylib            0x0000000111f06145 start";
}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff91dae654 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00000001018f7274 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff9497f76e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff91dae209 -[NSException raise] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x000000010bc8c9d9 -[IBAbstractMessageChannelToolProxy _errorByAddingAdditionalCrashInformationToError:orRaiseIfNeededOnFailure:shouldRaiseOnFailures:waitForCrashLog:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x000000010bc8c8fd -[IBAbstractMessageChannelToolProxy errorByAddingAdditionalCrashInformationToError:orRaiseIfNeededOnFailure:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x000000011054c06e (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x00000001105413d3 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x000000010ba8d51d -[IBPlatformToolRequester processRequests] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9  0x000000010192dc9c __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 10  0x00007fff94d8d323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11  0x00007fff94d88c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff94d8c365 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff94d8decc _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff94d8b6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15  0x00007fff94d99fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff96cac637 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 17  0x00007fff96caa40d start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)


abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
IBAssertionFailure

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91dae66c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001018f7274 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 194
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9497f76e objc_exception_throw + 43
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91dae209 -[NSException raise] + 9
4   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010bc8c9d9 -[IBAbstractMessageChannelToolProxy _errorByAddingAdditionalCrashInformationToError:orRaiseIfNeededOnFailure:shouldRaiseOnFailures:waitForCrashLog:] + 178
5   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010bc8c8fd -[IBAbstractMessageChannelToolProxy errorByAddingAdditionalCrashInformationToError:orRaiseIfNeededOnFailure:] + 98
6   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x000000011054c06e IBUISegmentConfiguration + 4812
7   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x00000001105413d3 IBIsObjectIllegalCocoaTouchOutletEndPoint + 10699
8   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010ba8d51d -[IBPlatformToolRequester processRequests] + 1161
9   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010192dc9c __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 106
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff94d8d323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff94d88c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff94d8c365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff94d8decc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff94d8b6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff94d99fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff96cac637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff96caa40d start_wqthread + 13

    Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9730d136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
    1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff979cb220 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 343
    2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff979c10d8 -[NSConditionLock lockWhenCondition:beforeDate:] + 232
    3   com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x00000001082c8ea6 -[IBSemaphore decrementWithTimeout:] + 179
    4   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010ba8ccea -[IBPlatformToolRequester waitForRequestWithID:timeout:] + 352
    5   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bb8f6f6 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager autolayoutStatusForArbitrationUnitContainingObject:] + 200
    6   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bb903ea -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager isItemMisplaced:] + 69
    7   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bb90a4b __61-[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager itemsWithCleanAutolayoutStatus]_block_invoke + 42
    8   com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x00000001082598cd -[NSSet(IBSetAdditions) ib_setByFilteringUsingBlock:] + 246
    9   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bb909f0 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager itemsWithCleanAutolayoutStatus] + 145
    10  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bb829a7 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager preserveCleanAutolayoutStatusDuring:] + 55
    11  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bb6b59c -[IBDocument preserveCleanAutolayoutStatusDuring:] + 79

12  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bd2c9be -[IBResourceManager synchronizeObjectPropertyValuesWithVariantContext] + 112
13  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bd29de7 __66-[IBResourceManager setupVariantContextWithContainerRepositories:]_block_invoke + 870
14  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102ef7cac -[IDEMediaResourceVariantContext registerVariantContextObserverWithOptions:block:] + 194
15  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bd299a0 -[IBResourceManager setupVariantContextWithContainerRepositories:] + 493
16  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bd29f4b -[IBResourceManager setResourceProvidingContainer:] + 196
17  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bb45d77 -[IBDocument setResourceProvidingContainer:] + 79
18  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bb449eb -[IBDocument refreshWorkspaceSourcedContent] + 120
19  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bb44cbe -[IBDocument registerWorkspaceDocument:forEditorViewController:] + 271
20  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010ba2fa3b -[IBAbstractDocumentEditor viewDidInstall] + 166
21  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000010bd7ebb8 -[IBStoryboardDocumentEditor viewDidInstall] + 51
22  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000101f4240f -[DVTViewController _didInstallContentView:] + 244
23  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000101d458bc -[DVTControllerContentView _viewDidInstall] + 330
24  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000101d4516c -[DVTControllerContentView viewDidMoveToWindow] + 97
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff904a0997 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 3274
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9049dc83 -[NSView addSubview:] + 463
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9054aea3 -[NSView setSubviews:] + 947
28  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000101d379a1 -[DVTBorderedView setContentView:] + 193
29  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102928f43 -[IDEEditorContext _setEditorView] + 324
30  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102ae75eb -[IDEEditorContext setupNewEditor:] + 946
31  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102ae91f2 __91-[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:]_block_invoke + 1311
32  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010293c01b -[IDEEditorContext _performBlockInsideReentrantGuard:] + 132
33  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010293be6e -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] + 3521
34  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010296f805 -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:withContentsOfURL:documentExtension:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] + 1713
35  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102aeace0 -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenNavigableItem:withContentsURL:documentExtensionIdentifier:locationToSelect:annotationRepresentedObject:stateDictionary:annotationWantsIndicatorAnimation:exploreAnnotationRepresentedObject:highlightSelection:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] + 3652
36  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102aec74b -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenEditorHistoryItem:previousHistoryItemOrNil:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] + 955
37  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102ae82a7 -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorHistoryItem:previousHistoryItemOrNil:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] + 381
38  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010296d9fe -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorHistoryItem:updateHistory:] + 346
39  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010296cc01 -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorHistoryItemFromStateSaving:] + 448
40  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001029a217d -[IDEEditorBasicMode _setPersistentRepresentation:forIdentifier:] + 519
41  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102db60be __60-[IDEEditorModeViewController _setPersistentRepresentation:]_block_invoke + 84
42  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91ce3536 __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 70
43  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91ce3469 -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 297
44  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001029688ce -[IDEEditorModeViewController _setPersistentRepresentation:] + 201
45  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001029686d1 -[IDEEditorModeViewController revertStateWithDictionary:] + 170
46  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010177797b -[DVTStateToken _pullStateFromDictionary:] + 327
47  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010177779d -[DVTStateToken pullStateFromRepository] + 168
48  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102948f18 -[IDEViewController revertState] + 48
49  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102922bc0 -[IDEEditorArea _updateStateSavingRegistrations] + 442
50  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010294b48f -[IDEEditorArea _refreshEditorContextsAndPreserveCurrentEditorHistoryStack:] + 705
51  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000102b27d0a __31-[IDEEditorArea viewDidInstall]_block_invoke + 429
52  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001019081ab __73-[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke183 + 83
53  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101883d78 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 75
54  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001017375fc -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 328
55  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9799aa93 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 382
56  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff97999c68 NSKeyValueDidChange + 463
57  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9799e7cd -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 118
58  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000102335a12 __81-[IDEWorkspace _finishLoadingAsynchronously:shouldUpgradeFromSimpleFilesFocused:]_block_invoke + 321
59  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000102335c6a __81-[IDEWorkspace _finishLoadingAsynchronously:shouldUpgradeFromSimpleFilesFocused:]_block_invoke321 + 59
60  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff97ace108 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
61  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff979ba725 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 97
62  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff979993bc -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
63  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff97998fc3 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
64  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff94d88c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
65  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff94d94cbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 861
66  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91d01c79 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
67  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91cbe30f __CFRunLoopRun + 2159
68  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91cbd858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
69  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8fcc52df RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
70  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8fcc505a ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
71  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8fcc4e9b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
72  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90488cf1 _DPSNextEvent + 964
73  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff904884a0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
74  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000101e5e6fd -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237
75  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9047c463 -[NSApplication run] + 594
76  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90467914 NSApplicationMain + 1832
77  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9496e5c9 start + 1
```

While I see the problem originates from IB (An item that references the first attribute must have multiple baselines), I have no clue what to try and change in my storyboard file, which is rather big.

Anyone had the same fate? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may suggest to open your storyboard file as source
and remove baseline constraints from scenes
You may remove it one by one to localize error reason

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was that I had some contraints that were conflicting. I opened Main.storyboard with a text editor and removed the contraints tags from a couple of views and it let me open the file without crashing.